# What iptables rules should I add first in the 'ruleset'?

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, firewall

I am setting iptables up the following way:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

and I want to add the following rules:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.101-192.168.0.193 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m iprange --dst-range 192.168.0.101-192.168.0.193 -j DROP
```

I heard that the position of the rules in the ruleset may be considered when setting iptables for things to work properly as intended, ***so I would like to know what I should add firstly, the `-m conntrack` ones or the `-m iprange` ones?***

what I want to do by using the rules above is:

```
- DROP every INPUT
- except the ones needed by the connections ESTABLISHED at OUTPUT, so I can access internet normally.
- but, additionally, I want to DROP EVERY CONNECTION incoming from (and outcoming to) my local network
```

*I would like to get answers from multiple different people about this to be really sure about what to do.*

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want.  If you have an established connection to  your `192.168.0.101-192.168.0.193` range do you want it to keep working after you activate the rules?  Or do you want it dropped?

If you to drop packets to that range unconditionally, then add that first.

Comment: I want to always DROP connections to/from this range, I never want/need any connections to/from this range.

Comment: @LucasB. But isn't your own computer in that range?

Comment: yes, It is, what would be the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I always add the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rules first (in your case, see next paragraph). This tells the kernel to stop processing packets related to an already established connection (why waste time checking packets from a connection already passed by the firewall?). Additionally, it prevents your connection from being blocked while your setting up the rules over ssh ;)

You will need to allow the *lo* device if you are going to default to `DROP`. Otherwise, connections from applications on your computer will not be able to access services running on itself. For performance reasons (at least in theory), I usually add `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` as the very first rule in my chain.

If you are going to default `DROP` on `OUTPUT` chains as well (egress filtering), you'll need to consider the `lo` interface as well as the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rules for that chain too. Egress filtering gets a little trickier because you need to consider only allowing traffic out specific ports, or allow egress by IP or range (as hinted by @Michael Hampton).

The same considerations apply for the `FORWARD` chain also, however it's a similar to both `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains since you will have traffic traversing that chain in both directions. **ONLY IF** you are doing any routing for machines on another subnet connected to your computer.  Otherwise, the `FORWARD` chain will not be used.